# Can't resolve an olympiade probleme in simple way

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the value of (x^4 + y^4 + z^4), given that x, y, and z are real numbers satisfying the following two conditions:

x + y + z = 0

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1